# How to play vibrato on the clarinet?

Tags: technique, clarinet, vibrato

I've been playing the clarinet for some time now, and have wanted to extend my ability with it. While doing so, I ran into vibrato. Is there a good method to play vibrato on the clarinet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether and how to use vibrato is a stylistic and personal question, and the most common answer for classical clarinet players seems to be just don't.

Jazz players sometimes have doubled on sax and clarinet, and so brought their vibrato over from the sax. The most common technique for vibrato on the sax is to move the jaw up and down, using the same technique as for adjusting your intonation. This can also be done on clarinet. There is also lip and diaphragm vibrato.

I've been cautioned that diaphragm vibrato can make you sound like Kenny G, which would cause you to burn in hell for all eternity.

Comment: +1 for the caveat about eternal damnation. Unwitting diagram vibrato horrors averted.

Comment: Just curious, where does Sidney Bechet get his vibrato?

Comment: David Shiffrin (classical) used vibrato as well.  (I double on sax and find myself doing it from time to time too.)  I'm self-taught in vibrato, and on both sax and clarinet, slight changes in pressure in the embouchure is enough for my tastes.